# How to prioritize (or set scheduling policy for) the 'manager' and 'worker' threads of a process?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, scheduling, thread-priority

I'm running a process (on a Linux 3.x-based OS) in which:

- A few threads are 'manager' threads (for simplicity assume they make decisions regarding which worker threads should do what, but do not do any I/O and the amount of CPU time they need, altogether, is shorter/much shorter than the worker threads')
- More threads are 'worker' threads: They do heavy lifting computation-wise, and I have no problem with their being preempted at any time.

It's possible that there's oversubscription (i.e. more workers threads than twice the cores on an Intel processor with HT). Now, what I'm seeing is that the 'manager' threads don't get processor time frequently enough. They're not entirely 'starved', I just want to give them a boost. So, naturally I thought about setting different thread prioritization (I'm on Linux) - but then I noticed the different choices for thread schedulers and their effect. At this point I got confused, or rather - it's not clear to me:

- Which scheduling policy should I choose for the managers, and which for the workers?
- What should I set the thread priorities to (if at all)?
- Do I need to have my threads yield() occasionally?

**Notes:**

- I'm intentionally not saying anything about the language or thread pool mechanism. I want to ask this question in the more general setting.
- Please do not make assumptions about CPU cores. There may be many of them, or maybe just one, and perhaps I need workers (or workers and managers) on each core.
- The worker threads may or may not do I/O. Answers for the case of them not doing any I/O are welcome, though.
- I don't really need the system to be very responsive other than running my application. I mean, I'd rather be able to SSH in there and have my typing echoed to me without a significant delay, but no real restrictions there.

Comment: This, with the "Linux" tag, is an excellent question. Under Windows, the answer is obvious, sadly not so under Linux where lower priority threads still compete over CPU time unless you set a RT scheduler (which is pretty much no-go for a "normal" program).

Comment: @Damon: Yes, I should emphasize it's about a process on Linux. However, if you have a link to the obvious Windows answer, maybe it's not a bad idea to put it in a comment here for the non-Windows'ers among us.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer for Windows is that there's priority boost, and higher priority threads preempt lower priority ones. This ensures that the producer will run for 2 quantums after being signalled on an event (in a submit-wait-submit-wait loop) and will be "undisturbed" while posting tasks, and take zero CPU while waiting for results. You could optionally lower the workers slightly, so system response is better in presence of other (interactive) tasks while still utilizing 100% of the CPU. None of that really works the same under Linux, though.

Comment: The second obvious thing for Windows is using IOCP and over-subscribing if threads have to perform disk or network I/O as well. IOCP will wake waiting threads as another one blocks on I/O, resulting in a near perfect usage (a few extra context switches, but they're hardly avoidable). No such thing on Linux either.

Comment: One of the problems is that you shouldn't really have more worker threads than CPU cores - there's no reason for that. The worker threads should act on possibly lockless job queues. The manager thread simply needs to have higher priority than the workers. That's all there's to it.

Comment: @KubaOber: There is unluckily a lot more to it. First, having num_core consumers and one producer means that they will compete over CPU cores. Higher priority does help but does not prevent starvation, since scheduling is "fair" (unless you use a RT scheduler, but this will negatively impact other processes and may in the worst case make the system unresponsible). Then there's the possibility of worker threads blocking on I/O, which will lead to sub-optimal CPU usage if you have only num_cpu threads. Ideally there'd be a couple more of them which will take over when a worker blocks.

Comment: @KubaOber: You're forgetting hyperthreading capabilities... in which case you might want something like 2 x num_cores. Also, I did not guarantee that the worker threads don't do I/O at all. Finally, the number of worker threads may be dictated by considerations other than my performance-related preferences.

Comment: @Damon: Many thanks for the promotion of this question, and to everybody else for the comments so far. I already have at least a few avenues to explore.

Comment: By cores I mean stuff that you can schedule things to run on -- sorry, I should have been more specific. As for I/O - you're hopefully doing non-blocking I/O, so it shouldn't matter. Alas, there is no way to sanely answer this question without limiting it to a particular scenario. The general concept of a "manager" thread is way too broad to be useful IMHO.

Comment: @KubaOber: Non-blocking I/O only works for sockets. Files are always ready and will always deliver "immediately", even if that really means blocking for 20-30 milliseconds. For files, you have kernel aio and glibc aio, the former being horribly broken and the latter throwing an additional thread per request at the problem (which kind of works, but isn't precisely helping here).

Comment: @Damon How is kernel aio broken? I use it in all of my networking code and it seems to work OK (no select/poll anywhere in my codebase). For files yes I agree that the support depends on how the filesystem is coded, but I'd not call it aio's deficiency, but filesystem's.

Comment: @KubaOber: I'm surprised to hear that kernel aio even works with sockets, to my knowledge it doesn't (sure you are not talking of non-blocking?). It is broken insofar as it will silently revert from asynchronous to synchronous for non-foreseeable reasons and with no possibility for the user to avoid this or do anything about it. Also it will only work with unbuffered reads, which is in some way "broken" (since that's ill-advised for 99% of all applications), too.

Answer (score 8):

**UPD 12.02.2015**: I have run some experiments.

### Theory

There is obvious solution to change "manager" threads scheduler to RT (real-time scheduler that provides SCHED_DEADLINE/SCHED_FIFO policies). In this case "manager" threads will always have larger priority than most threads in a system, so they will almost always get CPU when they need it.

However, there is another solution that allows you to stay on *CFS scheduler*. Your description of purpose of "worker" threads is similiar to *batch* scheduling (in ancient times when computers were large, user has to put his job onto queue and wait hours till its done). Linux CFS supports batch jobs via SCHED_BATCH policy and dialog jobs via SCHED_NORMAL policy.

There is also useful comment in kernel code ([kernel/sched/fair.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/fair.c#L4956-4961)):

```
/*
 * Batch and idle tasks do not preempt non-idle tasks (their preemption
 * is driven by the tick):
 */
if (unlikely(p->policy != SCHED_NORMAL) || !sched_feat(WAKEUP_PREEMPTION))
    return;
```

So when "manager" thread or some other event awake "worker", latter will get CPU only if there are free CPUs in system or when "manager" will exhaust its timeslice (to tune it change the weight of task).

It seems that your problem couldn't be solved without changing of scheduler policies. If "worker" threads are very busy and "manager" are rarely wake up, they would get same `vruntime` bonus, so "worker" would always preempt "manager" threads (but you may increase their weight, so they would exhaust their bonus faster).

### Experiment

I have a server with 2 x Intel Xeon E5-2420 CPUs which gives us 24 hardware threads. To simulate two threadpools I used my own [TSLoad](https://github.com/myaut/tsload) workload generator (and fixed couple of bugs while running experiments :) ).

There were two threadpools: `tp_manager` with 4 threads and `tp_worker` with 30 threads, both running `busy_wait` workloads (just `for(i = 0; i < N; ++i);`) but with different number of loop cycles. `tp_worker` works in `benchmark` mode so it will run as many requests as it can and occupies 100% of CPU.

Here are sample config: https://gist.github.com/myaut/ad946e89cb56b0d4acde

3.12 (vanilla with debug config)

```
EXP  |              MANAGER              |     WORKER
     |  sched            wait    service | sched            service
     |  policy           time     time   | policy            time
33   |  NORMAL          0.045    2.620   |     WAS NOT RUNNING
34   |  NORMAL          0.131    4.007   | NORMAL           125.192
35   |  NORMAL          0.123    4.007   | BATCH            125.143
36   |  NORMAL          0.026    4.007   | BATCH (nice=10)  125.296
37   |  NORMAL          0.025    3.978   | BATCH (nice=19)  125.223
38   |  FIFO (prio=9)  -0.022    3.991   | NORMAL           125.187
39   |  core:0:0        0.037    2.929   | !core:0:0        136.719
```

3.2 (stock Debian)

```
EXP  |              MANAGER              |     WORKER
     |  sched            wait    service | sched            service
     |  policy           time     time   | policy            time
46   |  NORMAL          0.032    2.589   |     WAS NOT RUNNING
45   |  NORMAL          0.081    4.001   | NORMAL           125.140
47   |  NORMAL          0.048    3.998   | BATCH            125.205
50   |  NORMAL          0.023    3.994   | BATCH (nice=10)  125.202
48   |  NORMAL          0.033    3.996   | BATCH (nice=19)  125.223
42   |  FIFO (prio=9)  -0.008    4.016   | NORMAL           125.110
39   |  core:0:0        0.035    2.930   | !core:0:0        135.990
```

Some notes:

- All times are in milliseconds
- Last experiment is for setting affinities (advised by @PhilippClaßen): manager threads was bound to Core #0 while worker threads was bound to all cores except Core #0.
- Service time for manager threads increased two times, which is explainable by concurrency inside cores (processor has Hyper-Threading!)
- Using SCHED_BATCH + nice (TSLoad cannot set directly weight, but `nice` can do it indirectly) slightly reduces wait time.
- Negative wait time in SCHED_FIFO experiment is OK: TSLoad reserves 30us so it can do preliminary work / scheduler have time to do context switch / etc.. It seem that SCHED_FIFO is very fast.
- Reserving single core isn't that bad, and because it removed in-core concurrency, service time was significantly decreased

Comment: Some of the experiment results need to be articulated some more... EXP is the experiment index? If so, where are experiments 1-32? 'wait time' - wait from what until what? 'service time' - what exactly is measured? Is it per thread? Overall? What is the 'debug config' you added to the vanilla kernel?

Comment: @einpoklum experiments 1-32 were testing & calibrating. My kernel config is here: [config-3.12.6](pastebin.com/5eYTFYNz). Speaking of times - it is terms from [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory](Queueing theory), except first is actually _waiting_ time (my bad). TL;DR - waiting time is a time between _request_ arrival (`nanosleep` timer expiration) and real thread wakeup (if system is busy, scheduler may hold it), service time is difference between starting and finishing handling of _request_ (on busy system sched sometime interrupts it and time grows).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to myaut's answer, you could also bind the manager to specific CPUs ([sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity)) and the workers to the rest. Depending on your exact use case that can be very wasteful, of course.

Link: [Thread binding the CPU core](http://www.linuxalgorithm.com/3064392/)

Explicit yielding is generally not necessary, in fact often discouraged. To quote Robert Love in "Linux System Programming":

> In practice, there are few legitimate uses of sched_yield() on a proper preemptive multitasking system such as Linux. The kernel is fully capable of making the optimal and most efficient scheduling decisions - certainly, the kernel is better equipped than an individual application to decide what to preempt and when.

The exception that he mentions, is when you are waiting on external events, for example, caused by the user, hardware or by another process. That is not the case, in your example.

Comment: Philipp, I don't want to waste an entire CPU core on management work just to avoid starvation of manager threads. Remember the entirety of the CPU work they require can be much much shorter than the worker threads'. To be explicit, consider the case in which they take altogether 1% of a time on a single CPU core.

Comment: When controlling core affinity manually you have to try really, really hard to get a result better than just leaving the Linux kernel to sort it out itself. Even if you manage to get a better result you then have to worry about the architecture of all the different machines the application is going to be run on; each one will require a different approach to core affinity. Probably best left well alone. Certainly you should address thread priorities and scheduling first.

Comment: @bazza Good comment, I completely agree. Just wanted to mention it as an alternative if you are not concerned about platform independence. myaut's answer is certainly the better and more general approach. It is very difficult to even slightly beat the Kernel, while it is easy to get it wrong. It is also likely to be slower on different platforms or possibly when your architecture or work load changes.

Answer (score 2):

An addition to myaut's excellent answer is to consider trying a kernel with the CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT patch set applied. This makes some fairly heavy-weight changes to how the kernel does scheduling, the net result being that scheduling latency becomes a lot more deterministic.

Used in combination with getting relative thread priorities correct (managers > workers) with either of myaut's suggestion (and especially with SCHED_FIFO) can yield very good results.

Comment: Link, please? Also, not disrespecting scheduling overhead determinism - how does that promote my goal? If the mean scheduling delay remains similar for the 'manager' threads, I'm not sure I'll benefit all that much from the lower variance.

Comment: @einpoklum, links: depends on your distro. I think Ubuntu do a package for a PREEMPT_RT kernel precompiled, which makes installation really easy. Otherwise, see https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page. How it helps? If you're seeing a situation whereby your management threads aren't being reliably scheduled even after sorting out relative thread priorities, that'll be because the stock kernel isn't itself pre-emptible (a design decision in favour of throughput). Other tasks making system calls can stop the kernel attending to scheduling your threads. PREEMPT_RT changes that.

Comment: @einpoklum, you might also like to use FTRACE (see http://omappedia.org/wiki/Installing_and_Using_Ftrace). This is an excellent way of visualising what's going on in your system, especially if you follow this: http://omappedia.org/wiki/Installing_and_Using_Ftrace#Sched_switch_viewer